# SynchronousQueue processing and ordered output

Tags: java, concurrency, queue

I would like to achieve something like this:

Notifications N1, N2, N3, ..., Nn goes to the SynchronousQueue. Queue is processing by 10 threads (managed by ExecutorService). Time of each action processed by threads is rather constant, let's say that action of thread is just decorate message. My expectation is that as an output I will have an order which is exactly the same as on input side: N1, N2, N3, ..., Nn.
Just thinking about solution so cannot provide any code samples. I don't know how to perform synchronization on the output side. Solution in my head generates output sequences where order can be different than expected.

Comment: Ok, to get an answer you need to ask a question.  Also you need to say what you have tried e.g. are you using an ExecutorService, and what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an ExecutorService, you can have a thread output the results.

```
ExecutorService multiThreaded = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N);
ExecutorService outputThread = Executors.newSingleThreadedPool();

Future future = multiThreaded.submit(new Callable<Object>() {
      public Object call() throws Exception {
            /// do some work
            return theResult;
      }
});
outputThread.submit(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
           Object theResult = future.get();
           // output the result
     }
});
```

The results will be in the order you add them to the outputThread.